# If I try to send to send ether to the standard token contract, the tx is rejected. Even if function() is modified as below. Why?

Tags: solidity, tokens

```
 /* If I change it like that it still fails */
    function () {
        amount += msg.value;     
    }
```

Is there something like, it's generally not possible to send eth to a token contract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Solidity >= 0.4, you will need to add `payable` to the function for it to accept Ether.

```
function() payable {
    amount += msg.value;
}
```